# Why is the covariance of an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process symmetric and positive semi-definite?

Tags: normal-distribution, brownian-motion, covariance, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

I have been working with the d-dimensional Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process $dX_t^{\epsilon}=-QX_t^{\epsilon}dt + \epsilon dB_t$, $X_0^{\epsilon}=x \in \mathbb{R}$. I know that, by Ito's formula, you can obtain its strong solution as
$$X_t^\epsilon(x)=e^{-Qt}x+\epsilon \int_0^te^{-Q(t-s)}dBs.$$

Where $\int_0^te^{-Q(t-s)}dBs$ is a Wiener integral and so $\int_0^te^{-Q(t-s)}dBs\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\int_0^te^{-2Q(t-s)}ds)$. Also, I assumed that $x, \epsilon$ and $Q$ are fixed, and $Q$ is invertible and with all of its eigenvalues with positive real component. With this, I computed $$\int_0^te^{-2Q(t-s)}ds=\frac{Q^{-1}}{2}(Id - e^{-2Qt})$$
and so, by using the properties of normal distributions $$X_t^\epsilon(x) \sim \mathcal{N}(e^{-Qt}x, \epsilon^2 \frac{Q^{-1}}{2}(Id - e^{-2Qt}))$$

My question here is, how can I determine that $\epsilon^2 \frac{Q^{-1}}{2}(Id - e^{-2Qt})$ is indeed a covariance matrix? (i.e that it is positive semi-definite and symmetric)

EDIT: I think that what makes no sense to me, is that supposedly one could obtain the invariant meassure $\mu$ by making $t\to \infty$. However, by the hypothesis on $Q's$ eigenvalues one gets that
$$\epsilon^2 \frac{Q^{-1}}{2}(Id - e^{-2Qt}) \to \frac{\epsilon^2 Q^{-1}}{2}$$

And so, $\mu \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \frac{\epsilon^2 Q^{-1}}{2})$, however without any more restrictions for $Q$, $\frac{\epsilon^2 Q^{-1}}{2}$ would not be a covariance matrix.

Comment: The issue with your solution is the way you compute the variance of that Wiener integral. For a centred random vector $X$, its covariance matrix is given by $\mathbb{E}(XX^T)$. Now, replace $X = \int_0^t e^{-Q(t-s)} dB_s$ to get the actual OU covariance.

Comment: So, when in the literature they show that the Wiener integral $\int_0^t g(s)dBs \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \int_0^t g^2(s) ds)$ they are using the notation $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma)$ instead of $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$?

Comment: No, in that case they mean the one-dimensional Wiener integral (i.e. $g(s)$ is scalar-valued).

Comment: But doesn't the d-dimensional Wiener integral works as a random vector, where each component is the one-dimensional case?

Comment: Not quite. If $B_t$ is $n$-dimensional Brownian motion and $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix then the $i$-th coordinate of $X_t = \int_0^t A dB_s$ is $X_t^{(i)} = \sum_{k=1}^n \int_0^t A_{ik} dB_s^{(k)}$. Now try to calculate the covariance of the vector $X_t$.

Comment: I'll try, by chance do you have a reference where I can look this up?